# Unable to change price

Tags: price, magmi

I've an urgent issue that I don't know how to troubleshoot. I'd be grateful for some suggestions.

When I change the price for a particular product in the backend, it doesn't change on the frontend. I've done the usual reindex and clear cache - but no go.

**edit:**
I've cleaned this question up, removing a lot of additional issues which may have been a distraction. Further troublshooting of this issue gives the following updates:

- refreshed caches, and restarted apache - no change
- creating a new simple product in the backend, then changing that - does work!

I use MAGMI to make my updates to products, adding them, changing prices etc, so perhaps this is the problem. Somehow, the Magmi process has 'broken' the products somehow.

Does anyone have ideas on how I can troubleshoot that further, and somehow fix? The products look fine in the admin screen - they just can't be updated on the front end.

(If I make the update via Magmi, it works though)

Comment: It is either Cache, Index or a combination of the both. Try restarting Apache

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update: I noticed that I didn't use **MAGMI_IGNORE** correctly on every field. Having recreated the Magmi import file (hopefully correctly this time) things seem to be working better!!

So for others that might find this post, if you use Magmi for multi language sites, do take care that you only ask Magmi to update the fields needed for the second language, and use **MAGMI_IGNORE** for the things which it can skip.

Answer (score 1):

Brents answer is a good start, would like to add. Some processes I usually follow when things seem to stop working.

1. Check the Magento Log Files for any errors
2. Check the apache error log files.

Brendan

Comment: Thanks. I will check the logs. However in the meantime, I was able to force the change by uploading the prices via MAGMI. I will close the question for now then!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I was able to force the change by uploading the prices via MAGMI.

My problems continue - so I will update the question with additional details.

Comment: Recommend to update new info on your question instead add answer Hope it fix!

Comment: thanks - indeed, I've cleaned up the question, and added the latest status.